# Ubuntu freezes during boot after upgrade to 18.04 LTS from 17.10

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 18.04

I have a couple of VirtualBox ubuntu VMs with Guest Additions installed: 16.04, 16.10, 17.10, all of them work fine prior to upgrade. In fact, I just did a do-release-upgrade yesterday from 16.10 to 17.10 and everything works fine.

Today, seeing that 18.04 LTS has been released, I upgraded two of my 17.10, and both of them failed to boot after upgrade. They flash 4 times between the small verbose boot sequence screen and a full screen black screen before freezing. Both of them have very similar failure.

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS failed to boot after upgrade. Started Display Manger.... link was shut down..]

[image: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS failed to boot after upgrade. Started GNOME Display Manger... kernel crash signatures....as shut down..]

I attempted to hold <kbd>shift</kbd> during boot to enter recovery and command prompt to

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-*
```

but the problem persists.

My host is 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate on a Z77 platform with a nVidia GTX 750 Ti graphics card. VirtualBox version 5.2.8 r121009 with Extension Pack installed.

Answer (score 1):

My machines were able to boot normally after disabling 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox.

Settings > Display > Screen > Acceleration > Enable 3D Acceleration (Uncheck)

[image: Disable 3D Acceleration in VirtualBox]

An alternative fix is welcome because I had been using 3D Acceleration fine since forever so I do not understand why it has to be disabled, or if it is really the culprit. Since the feature was working before 18.04 I suspect it to be a new bug unrelated to previous issues.

Comment: I get the same errors on bare metal, is there a way to do this within the guest system?